# How to generate random alphanumeric in MySQL restricting to some letters and numbers?

Tags: mysql

How to generate random alphanumeric in MySQL restricting to some letters and numbers

For example I want to generate random alphanumeric which not contain 0 , 1 , o and l

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should specify length restriction also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you response. I build a query which works fine for me..

```
SELECT CONCAT( 
    (SELECT  CASE WHEN a.aa='0' THEN 'a' 
                  WHEN a.aa='1' THEN 'b'  
                  WHEN a.aa='l' THEN 'g'  
                  WHEN a.aa='o' THEN 'q'  
                  ELSE a.aa  
             END AS d 
     FROM (SELECT LCASE(CONV(FLOOR(RAND()*36),10,36)) AS aa) AS a),
    (SELECT  CASE WHEN a.aa='0' THEN 'a'  
                  WHEN a.aa='1' THEN 'b'  
                  WHEN a.aa='l' THEN 'g'  
                  WHEN a.aa='o' THEN 'q'  
                  ELSE a.aa  
             END AS d  
     FROM (SELECT LCASE(CONV(FLOOR(RAND()*36),10,36)) AS aa) AS a),
    (SELECT  CASE WHEN a.aa='0' THEN 'a'  
                  WHEN a.aa='1' THEN 'b'  
                  WHEN a.aa='l' THEN 'g'  
                  WHEN a.aa='o' THEN 'q'  
                  ELSE a.aa  
             END AS d  
     FROM (SELECT LCASE(CONV(FLOOR(RAND()*36),10,36)) AS aa) AS a),
    (SELECT  CASE WHEN a.aa='0' THEN 'a'  
                  WHEN a.aa='1' THEN 'b'  
                  WHEN a.aa='l' THEN 'g'  
                  WHEN a.aa='o' THEN 'q'  
                  ELSE a.aa  
             END AS d 
     FROM (SELECT LCASE(CONV(FLOOR(RAND()*36),10,36)) AS aa) AS a),
    (SELECT  CASE WHEN a.aa='0' THEN 'a'  
                  WHEN a.aa='1' THEN 'b'  
                  WHEN a.aa='l' THEN 'g'  
                  WHEN a.aa='o' THEN 'q' ELSE a.aa  
                  END AS d 
     FROM (SELECT LCASE(CONV(FLOOR(RAND()*36),10,36)) AS aa) AS a),
    (SELECT  CASE WHEN a.aa='0' THEN 'a'  
                  WHEN a.aa='1' THEN 'b'  
                  WHEN a.aa='l' THEN 'g'  
                  WHEN a.aa='o' THEN 'q' ELSE a.aa  
             END AS d  
     FROM (SELECT LCASE(CONV(FLOOR(RAND()*36),10,36)) AS aa) AS a),
    (SELECT  CASE WHEN a.aa='0' THEN 'a'  
                  WHEN a.aa='1' THEN 'b'  
                  WHEN a.aa='l' THEN 'g'  
                  WHEN a.aa='o' THEN 'q'  
                  ELSE a.aa 
             END AS d 
     FROM (SELECT LCASE(CONV(FLOOR(RAND()*36),10,36)) AS aa) AS a)
)AS NAME
```

Answer (score 3):

You can generate random characters by using RAND() function and CHAR() function to get ascii character. The below example will give you 20 rows of alphanumeric (length of 5 characters) which will include characters that you have specified by using `HAVING` clause at the bottom.

`CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*10)+48)` will give you a random digit from 0 to 9
`CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*26)+65)` will give you a random upper case letter
`CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*26)+97)` will give you a random lower case letter
these are UNION-ed together then `ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1` will select a random one character out of them make it totally random for each character, this code is then cut and pasted 5 times to get a random string of 5 characters long.

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  (SELECT CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*10)+48) as chr UNION SELECT CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*26)+65) UNION SELECT CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*26)+97) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1),
  (SELECT CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*10)+48) as chr UNION SELECT CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*26)+65) UNION SELECT CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*26)+97) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1),
  (SELECT CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*10)+48) as chr UNION SELECT CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*26)+65) UNION SELECT CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*26)+97) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1),
  (SELECT CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*10)+48) as chr UNION SELECT CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*26)+65) UNION SELECT CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*26)+97) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1),
  (SELECT CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*10)+48) as chr UNION SELECT CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*26)+65) UNION SELECT CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*26)+97) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1)
             ) as randstr
FROM
  (SELECT 1 FROM 
   (SELECT 0 as v UNION SELECT 1)T1,
   (SELECT 0 as v UNION SELECT 2)T2,
   (SELECT 0 as v UNION SELECT 4)T3,
   (SELECT 0 as v UNION SELECT 8)T4,
   (SELECT 0 as v UNION SELECT 16)T5,
   (SELECT 0 as v UNION SELECT 32)T6
   )T
HAVING randstr NOT LIKE '%1%' 
   AND randstr NOT LIKE '%0%'
   AND randstr NOT LIKE '%o%'
   AND randstr NOT LIKE '%l%'
LIMIT 20
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/30059/0)

Alternately, you can write a function to generate a random string for you like below where you can specify length of string you want and have it check to exclude the 4 characters you have specified in your question

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION randString(in_length INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
BEGIN 
  SET @len = 0;
  SET @returnValue = "";
  WHILE (@len < in_length) DO
    SET @randChar = "0";
    WHILE (@randChar IN ("0","1","o","l")) DO
       SET @randChar = (      SELECT CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*10)+48) as chr 
                        UNION SELECT CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*26)+65) 
                        UNION SELECT CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*26)+97) 
                        ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1);
    END WHILE;
    SET @returnValue = CONCAT(@returnValue,@randChar);
    SET @len = @len + 1;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN @returnValue;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5842/1/0)